# splitting a data.table, then modifying by reference

Tags: r, data.table

I have a use-case where I need to split a data.table, then apply different modify-by-reference operations to each partition. However, splitting forces copying of each table.

Here's a toy example on the iris dataset:

```
#split the data
DT <- data.table(iris)
out <- split(DT, DT$Species)

#assign partitions to global environment
NAMES <- as.character(unique(DT$Species))
lapply(seq_along(out), function(x) {
assign(NAMES[x], out[[x]], envir=.GlobalEnv)})

#modify by reference, same function applied to different columns for different partitions
#would do this programatically in real use case
virginica[ ,summ:=sum(Petal.Length)]
setosa[ ,summ:=sum(Petal.Width)]

#rbind all (again, programmatic)
do.call(rbind, list(virginica, setosa))
```

Then I get the following warning:

```
 Warning message:
 In `[.data.table`(out$virginica, , `:=`(cumPedal, cumsum(Petal.Width))) :
  Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a copy of the whole table so that := can add this new column by reference.
```

I know this is related to putting data.tables in lists. Is there any workaround for this use case, or a way to avoid using `split`? Note that in the real case, I want to modify by reference programatically, so hardcoding a solution won't work.

Comment: You shouldn't need to `split` a `data.table`. You might be looking for the `.EACHI` function in `data.table`.

Comment: The problem is that the `j` expression is actually different for each partition. I am programatically building different `j` expressions for each partition.

Comment: I'll update the example to show where I'm going with this.

Comment: So, to be clear, you're looking for each group to create a new (differently named) column with a function applied to different columns? Or are the functions totally different too?

Comment: in my real example, function is the same, column name is the same, BUT function is applied to different columns, depending on the group.

Comment: Then I think that `.EACHI` would work. Give me a few minutes to switch from a phone to a computer :-)

Comment: Modified question to make clearer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of using `.EACHI` to achieve what it sounds like you're trying to do:

```
## Create a data.table that indicates the pairs of keys to columns
New <- data.table(
  Species = c("virginica", "setosa", "versicolor"), 
  FunCol = c("Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Sepal.Length"))

## Set the key of your original data.table
setkey(DT, Species)

## Now use .EACHI
DT[New, temp := cumsum(get(FunCol)), by = .EACHI][]
#      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species  temp
#   1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa   0.2
#   2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa   0.4
#   3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa   0.6
#   4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa   0.8
#   5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa   1.0
#  ---                                                                  
# 146:          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica 256.9
# 147:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica 261.9
# 148:          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica 267.1
# 149:          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica 272.5
# 150:          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica 277.6

## Basic verification
head(cumsum(DT["setosa", ]$Petal.Width), 5)
# [1] 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1.0
tail(cumsum(DT["virginica", ]$Petal.Length), 5)
```

Comment: This solution will work, however the function being called must be vectorized, since we can't set by = unique key